# How to use regex in groovy map

Tags: collections, groovy, dictionary

i have a map similar to this.

```
     xxx-10.name ='welcome'
     xxx-10.age  ='12'
     xxx-10.std  ='2nd'

     xxx-12.name ='welcome'
     xxx-12.age  ='12'
     xxx-12.std  ='2nd'

     yyy-10.name ='welcome'
     yyy-10.age  ='12'
     yyy-10.std  ='2nd'

     yyy-12.name ='welcome'
     yyy-12.age  ='12'
     yyy-12.std  ='2nd'
```

wen user gives xxx i have to return the submap with all xxx entries, irrespective of the number associated with it. Is there any way to achieve this using regex ? or  with out iterating over the keys?

SubMap i can get using the utility..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do what you want.

```
def fileContents = '''xxx-10.name ='welcome'
                     |xxx-10.age  ='12'
                     |xxx-10.std  ='2nd'
                     |xxx-12.name ='welcome'
                     |xxx-12.age  ='12'
                     |xxx-12.std  ='2nd'
                     |yyy-10.name ='welcome'
                     |yyy-10.age  ='12'
                     |yyy-10.std  ='2nd'
                     |yyy-12.name ='welcome'
                     |yyy-12.age  ='12'
                     |yyy-12.std  ='2nd'''.stripMargin()

// Get a Reader for the String (this could be a File.withReader)
Map map = new StringReader( fileContents ).with {
  // Create a new Properties object
  new Properties().with { p ->
    // Load the properties from the reader
    load( it )
    // Then for each name, inject into a map
    propertyNames().collectEntries {
      // Strip quotes off the values
      [ (it): p[ it ][ 1..-2 ] ]
    }
  }
}

findByPrefix = { pref ->
  map.findAll { k, v ->
    k.startsWith( pref )
  }
}

findByPrefix( 'xxx' )
```

Fingers crossed you don't delete this question ;-)

Answer (score 5):

There is a filter function for collections in groovy. See [API](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html#findAll%28groovy.lang.Closure%29)

```
def result = [a:1, b:2, c:4, d:5].findAll { it.value % 2 == 0 }
assert result.every { it instanceof Map.Entry }
assert result*.key == ["b", "c"]
assert result*.value == [2, 4]
```

In your case when searching for `yourSearchString` using [String.startsWith()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29):

```
map.findAll { it.key.startsWith(yourSearchString) }
```

Comment: Better to use `startsWith` as that's what he's interested in as I do in [my answer of 10 minutes ago](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13156735/6509)